# Bundler can't resolve a version for sorbet-static that matches my current platform; Found sorbet-static ... that did not match the current platform

Tags: ruby, bundler, sorbet

On an intel Mac running Ventura 13.3, I am getting this problem when trying to `bundle install` :

```
Found sorbet-static (0.5.9019-x86_64-linux),
sorbet-static (0.5.9019-x86_64-linux) that did not match the current platform
```

My colleagues, also running on Intel macs but not on Ventura 13.3 (they are running earlier versions of macOS), are able to bundle install just fine.

The gemfile has Sorbet locked to:

```
  gem 'sorbet', '= 0.5.9019'
```

the problem appears to be with sorbet-static, which is a dependency of sorbet

interestingly, this is an older version of sorbet (which unfortunately our app has dependancies around). My colleagues' macbooks seem to pick up the build for `0.5.9019-x86_64-linux` or `0.5.9019-universal-darwin-21`, but my mac won't pick up either of those versions.

If I examine the available builds on Rubygems (which you can see here)
https://rubygems.org/gems/sorbet-static/versions?page=40

[image]

You'll notice there is no universal-darwin-22 build of this version of this gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/3972) to get a better understanding of both the problem and how to resolve it. In short:

> Sorbet only support `HEAD`, so we have no plans to update old gem versions.
>
> If you want to hack around this, all `universal-darwin-*` binaries are identical.
>
> ...
>
> You could unpack the universal-darwin-19 gem, sed 19 to 20 everywhere, and re-tar it up, and host the `*.gem` file somewhere.
>
> Otherwise, i'd recommend upgrading. You're on a 9 month old sorbet version—we've made a lot of improvements since then.

The real answer is that you need to upgrade your gem version. I don't know why you're pinned to a two year old version of the library but I imagine that the pain of upgrading is less than attempting to create your own custom build of the gem for a specific Darwin version.